# Global readable private keys found in storage/emulated/0/data - Possible security risk?

Tags: encryption, privacy

I found following global readable files in `/storage/emulated/0/data/IMS`:

`cert.pem`

`private_key.pem`

I have full access to this files with my file-manager/text-editor, so I think any other app will have full access too! It seems to be a privacy/security issue.

Information:

`Cert.pem line 6: "Issuer: CN=Samsung RCS Client"`

(Wikipedia: RCS="Rich Communication Services")
I moved `private_key.pem` to another directory, it has been replaced by a new different `private_key.pem` file.

Is this a possible security risk?

Comment: Congrats to your find! And now what's your question? :)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Don't we have a new security problem if any app can read or modify this files?

Comment: Not sure who "we" is. Point is, from the location, that belongs to "some app" (and not the system). Apart from that, it's something Samsung specific. And there's nothing "we" can do about it. Maybe you should report it to the dev of the related app? "IMS", whatever that is?

Comment: are you saying you have a samsung private key ? can i have a copy?

Comment: looks like it's connected to a messenger client ?

Comment: I mean all Samsumg (or possibly any other manufacturer?) Android smartphone user.

Comment: @moonbutt74: Of course not!

Comment: I think, IMS means Instant Massaging Service.

Comment: @Izzy: It could be a prolem for any android user.

Comment: But it is nothing we can solve here. Only the devs of the related app can.

Answer (score 2):

A globally-readable private key is almost certainly a vulnerability. A globally-readable certificate is generally not. You appear to have both, so you've very likely found a vulnerability.

Your next step would be to either report it to the vendor (probably Samsung) or find a security researcher who can investigate further.

According to a [blog post](http://security.samsungmobile.com/smrreport.html), Samsung Mobile security issues can be sent to `mobile.security@samsung.com`. In theory, that email should be staffed by someone clueful about security (unlike first-tier customer support), so you should get a reasonable response. When contacting them, you should let them know about this question, so they realize it's already been disclosed.